# Selenium: Google Sign-In pages looking different

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Headless version to automate signing into Google. This is the webpage I see on my normal chrome:

[image]

And this is the webpage the Selenium Chrome browser sees:

[image]

As a result, the xPaths I get from what I see are not going to work on what the Selenium Chrome browser sees. So my question is how do I view the version of the page the Selenium Chrome browser sees to get the relevant xPaths ?

Here's how I'm starting my chrome:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1340,900")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**EDIT** It turns out google does not let you sign in via Selenium, here's what I got after I entered the email address and pressed next:

[image]

Comment: Just get the correct `xpaths` from selenium directly

Comment: what do you mean? How would I do that?

Comment: Are you explicitly passing in a `user-agent` parameter??

Comment: In selenium chrome right click and Inspect element

Comment: @CavinDsouza no

Comment: Check if the URL that you provide in the code and that you see on the browser are the same, I tried to reciprocate this issue with the URL as `https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin` and I get 1st window like you've shown, The other option would be is to right click and inspect element on the selenium chrome browser itself or you could always use getPageSource() to see the complete source

Comment: @WilfredClement The urls are the same. I cannot inspect element in the selenium chrome as I'm using it in headless mode!

Comment: fair enough, but you should be able to see the console logs right ? Why don't you try a 
`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` and also give us the URL that you use in the code and we'll give it a try as well

Comment: @WilfredClement okay, I'll give that a go!

Comment: @WilfredClement I am able to see the page source!

Comment: Great, and that should help you find the relevant xpaths now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212534/discussion-between-wilfred-clement-and-ayudh).

Answer (score 0):

i exactly not understand what you wont
but if you wont to check chrome browser version : 
1.Open your chrome browser.
2.go to setting 
3.in the left side bar found About 
4.and then wait for a moment to check your last version of chrome browser.

> Blockquote If you download last chrome-driver - you must be Update your chrome browser to working.
>   Blockquote your chrome-driver and Chrome-Browser should to be the same Version!

Comment: I understand, I'll try to make sure the chrome versions are the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the values from the google website that selenium opens? Stay on that website, don't close it and don't go back to the site that you see when you do it manually. Inspect the site that selenium opens.

I can't see why that wouldn't work...

Maybe try to upload the entire code, then i'll take a look at it!

Comment: I can't get the values from the google website that selenium opens as I'm running this in headless mode. The script is running on a server.